# Problems with 'implode' in query Yii2

Tags: php, pdo, yii2, implode

Good morning! I 'm trying to do a query with the 'IN' clause using 'Implode'. The problem is that whenever I return one record. Just take the first value of the array and puts it in the IN...

```
$array = $fields -> exports;
         $values = implode(",", $array);
         $export = Users_logs::find()
                -> where(['IN', 'Id', [$values]])
                -> all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use implode, pass array directly

```
where(['IN', 'Id', $array])
```

or

```
where(['Id' => $array]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! as I may have occurred , this works fine . Greetings!